# Cannot resolve method "setCvCameraViewListener"

Tags: android, opencv, android-studio

I'm trying to build an app using OpenCV and Android Studio, showing the cam and object position. In my activity I have

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
```

"this" is underlined in red and the error is `Cannot resolve method "setCvCameraViewListener"`.

Comment: Give us more context: what kind of object is `this` ? where are you calling this method from ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure your activity implements the CvCameraViewListener2 and openCV version is correct on the OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.**OPENCV_VERSION_3_0_0**, this, mLoaderCallback);
This worked for me :)

```
    public class camera extends Activity implements CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener2
    {
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(new CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCameraViewStopped() {

        }

        @Override
        public Mat onCameraFrame(Mat inputFrame) {
            return null;
        }
    });
```

[here](http://docs.opencv.org/java/2.4.9/org/opencv/android/CameraBridgeViewBase.CvCameraViewListener.html) the ref.